# Is there a way to display a picture on my website, only if the picture is not a null value on a list?

Tags: html, angular

I'm setting up a User Interface using a simple database and angular, where users can post a message, either with only a message, or with a picture attached to the message.

By doing some research, I found out about the built in ngIf conditions, where you can display variables if the variable doesn't hold a null value.

Here is my code and the output:

```
 <div ng-repeat="m in chatDetailsCtrl.messageList">
            <!-- This card prodives space for the message and Like/dislike buttons -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <!-- Card Title is the person who wrote the message -->
                            <span class="card-title">{{m.user_ID}}</span>
                            <!-- Here comes the message text -->
                            <p> {{m.post_msg}}
                                <div> <span class="new badge light-blue">{{m.post_date}}</span></div>
                            <p *ngIf="m.photo_url">
                                <img src="{{m.photo_url}}"  width="100" height="100">
                            </p>
                               {{m.post_date|date("m/d/Y")}} -->
                            </p>
                            <td><a class="waves-effect  light blue lighten-1 btn-small" ng-click="chatDetailsCtrl.postDetails(m.post_ID)">Post Details</a></td>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-action">

                            <a class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light blue" ><i class="material-icons">thumb_up
                            </i></a> <span ng-bind= "m.likes">  </span>
                            <a class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light blue"><i class="material-icons">thumb_down
                            </i></a><span ng-bind="m.dislikes">  </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: Here is the output]

I want to see if m.post_url contains a value. When null, I want to skip adding this variable to my website.

For example, last post, without a picture, I want it to look like this:

[image: Expected output]

Sorry for my bad english, english is not my first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you are mixing angularJs syntax with new angular.

if you are using angularjs use `ng-if` in your image tag. it works properly.

as I can see you are using ng-repeat and ng-bind you are using angularjs and not angular.

so in your image tag use

```
 <p ng-if="m.photo_url">
      <img src="{{m.photo_url}}"  width="100" height="100">
  </p>
```